# Downloading image with urllib [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, windows, urllib

Im making an script that download a png file from a certain site in python 3.6

`import urllib.request`

`name = "gato" + ".png"`

`urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/01/00/15/png-2702691_960_720.png', name)`

but i end with **[Errno 2] No such file or directory**
if i use
`urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/01/00/15/png-2702691_960_720.png', 'name.png')`
i get no such error

Answer (score 1):

it's not the best answer, but it do the same. good luck.

```
import requests

imageurl = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/01/00/15/png-2702691_960_720.png'
file = 'gato.png'

response = requests.get(imageurl)

with open(file, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```